# how to convert html table into json desired format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a  `html` table that i want to convert into `json` format but i'm not getting correctly.

the `resultant` `json` is not coming according to my `format`

**here is my table**

```
<table class="table" id="example-table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Product Name</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
         <td>flex board</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">3</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">5</td>
         <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
         <td>sign board</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">20</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">1</td>
         <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
         <td>flex board</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">30</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">1</td>
         <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
         <td>sign board</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">200</td>
         <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">19</td>
         <td>3800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="lastTotalRow">
         <td>total</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>3865</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**i want my desired result to be like this:**

```
{
   "flex_board": [
      {
         "Price": 3,
         "Quantity": 5,
         "Amount": 15
      },
      {
         "Price": 30,
         "Quantity": 1,
         "Amount": 30
      }
   ],
   "sign_board": [
      {
         "Price": 20,
         "Quantity": 1,
         "Amount": 20
      },
      {
         "Price": 200,
         "Quantity": 19,
         "Amount": 3800
      }
   ],
   "total": [
      {
         "Price": null,
         "Quantity": null,
         "Amount": 3865
      }
   ]
}
```

here is my jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/eabangalore/cCzqn/1601/

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to convert your `Array` into desired `Object`

```
$('#convert-table').click(function() {
  var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
  var result = table.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    var key = item["Product Name"].replace(/ /g, "_");
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push({
      Price: item.Price,
      Quantity: item.Quantity,
      Amount: item.Amount
    })
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(result);
});
```

jsFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/scorpy2007/cCzqn/1603/

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelectorAll` and `Array.from` to iterate the rows (*Comments inline*)

```
var allRows = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "tbody tr:not(:last-child)" ) ); //get all rows except last one

var map = {};

allRows.forEach( function( row ){
  var cells = row.children;
  var prodName = cells[0].innerText; //index by product name
  map[ prodName ] = map[ prodName ] || []; //initialize inner array
  map[ prodName ].push({ //push each row to the respective product name's index
     Price : cells[1].innerText,
     Quantity : cells[2].innerText,
     Amount : cells[3].innerText
  });
});

console.log( map );
```

**Demo**

```js
var allRows = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "tbody tr:not(:last-child)" ) ); //get all rows except last one

var map = {};

allRows.forEach( function( row ){
  var cells = row.children;
  var prodName = cells[0].innerText; //index by product name
  map[ prodName ] = map[ prodName ] || []; //initialize inner array
  map[ prodName ].push({ //push each row to the respective product name's index
     Price : cells[1].innerText,
     Quantity : cells[2].innerText,
     Amount : cells[3].innerText
  });
});

console.log( map );
```

```html
<table class="table" id="example-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
      <td>flex board</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">3</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">5</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
      <td>sign board</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">20</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">1</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
      <td>flex board</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">30</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">1</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="allTheQuotationRow">
      <td>sign board</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="priceChangeField">200</td>
      <td contenteditable="" class="quantityChangeField">19</td>
      <td>3800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lastTotalRow">
      <td>total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>3865</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring an array like that can be a complicated procedure, but thankfully there is a library called lodash that has a function called groupBy. It can fix your problem in a single line of code!
`_.groupBy(table, "Product Name")`

That's really it!
[Lodash Library](https://lodash.com/)

http://jsfiddle.net/nhc6m1af/

Answer (score 0):

You can use same tableToJSON data object in generating your customized format as shown below

```
 var jsondata={};
  table.forEach( function( data ){  
  var prodName = data["Product Name"];
  jsondata[ prodName ] = jsondata[ prodName ] ?jsondata[ prodName ]: [];  
  jsondata[ prodName ].push({   
     Price : data['Price'],
     Quantity : data['Quantity'],
     Amount : data['Amount']
  });
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y4vd3n1v/)